# How to make a file with variables of all project's text?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I use ReactJS to develop a web.I want to define all the texts in one class. like:

```
class ProjectsTexts {
     static var applicationName = "my application"
     static var internetConnectionError = "Please check your internet connection"
}
```

And then I can call them from my other classes. like:

```
function LoginView() {
    return (
        <header>
            <title>(ProjectsTexts.applicationName)</title>
        </header>
    );
}
```

Now if I want to change a text everywhere, I just need to change the variable's value.

Thank you. Also, sorry about my English.

Comment: use object in separate file . import and use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the classes are in the same file, you can simply do -

```
class ProjectsTexts {
     static applicationName = "my application";
     static internetConnectionError = "Please check your internet connection";
}
```

And use inside other classes

```
function LoginView() {
    return (
        <header>
            <title>{ProjectsTexts.applicationName}</title>
        </header>
    );
}
```

But, if they are in different files, you need to `export` and `import`.

```
class ProjectsTexts {
     static applicationName = "my application";
     static internetConnectionError = "Please check your internet connection";
}

export default ProjectsTexts;
```

And use inside other classes

```
import ProjectsTexts from '<path-to-file-here>';
...

function LoginView() {
    return (
        <header>
            <title>{ProjectsTexts.applicationName}</title>
        </header>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but after import "ProjectsTexts" class, in html section It is not detect as variable and use (ProjectsTexts.applicationName) as String

Comment: Oh.. need to use `{}` in place of `()` inside `<title>...</title>`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate file for constants -

**constants.js**

```
export default {
    applicationName: "my application"
    internetConnectionError: "Please check your internet connection"
}
```

& import it anywhere you want to use.

**LoginView.js**

```
import CONST from '../constants' // check if path is correct for you.

function LoginView() {
  return (
    <header>
        <title>{CONST.applicationName}</title>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but in "constants.js" file, it's gave me a error-> Line 2:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: my bad, as i used equal sign instead of : as its an object being exported. check it now

Comment: Thanks a lot. إut I think in "LoginView.js" file, need to use {} in place of () inside <title>...</title>.  I really appreciate it. That's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file `export` it and then `import` it where you want to use it.
Another option is to make it globally available via a store (redux). There are other ways to do this as well.